# Creating an annotation interface with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, jvm, byte-buddy

I'm trying use ByteBuddy to generate a simple annotation interface with a `String value()` attribute. I'm using the following code (Xtend syntax, but you get the idea):

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .makeInterface(Annotation)
  .merge(Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .name("fxxx.lang.Annotation")
  .defineMethod("value", TypeDescription.STRING)
  .withoutCode
  .make.load(class.classLoader).loaded
```

Without the `value()` method (i.e., if I remove the `defineMethod` and `withoutCode`) this works beautifully. However, as soon as I add an attribute/method to the annotation I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method value in class fxxx/lang/Annotation has illegal modifiers: 0x400
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.access$300(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:40)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader$ClassDefinitionAction.run(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:614)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader$ClassDefinitionAction.run(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.findClass(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:339)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.load(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:289)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$WrappingDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:342)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:128)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:85)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:5468)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:5457)
```

I am extremely baffled by this exception, because 0x400 is `ACC_ABSTRACT`, which is exactly what you'd expect for an interface method.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: seems like a complex way just to create an annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, just as I'm about to finish writing up my question, I remember that interface methods do not only need to be abstract, they also need to be public. Modifier value 0x400 indicates that the method is *only* abstract, but not public.

So, the simple fix was to add public visibility to the method attributes:

```
.defineMethod("value", TypeDescription.STRING, Visibility.PUBLIC)
```

Comment: Interface methods can also be `private`. But the absence of either, `public` or `private` implies package-private aka default access, which is not allowed for interface methods.

Comment: Good point, @Holger, I forgot that there's that possibility as well.

Comment: That's a missing validation in Byte Buddy. You'll get a better error message in a future version.

Comment: Thanks, @RafaelWinterhalter, that would be a nice improvement!